# self join condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

I have a confusion in self join condition
eg:i have a table named as 'employee' and column as employeeid,name,managerid
just a basic syntax

```
select e.employeeid,m.managerid
from employee e
left join employee m
**on e.managerid=m.employeeid
or e.employeeid=m.managerid**
```

please tell me differnce between the text with in **

Comment: The first one fetches the rows from e where e is the manager, and the second one fetches the rows e where e is the employee. M is the opposite.

Comment: What do you mean by "the difference"?  The difference between each line between the **s?

Comment: and if you're alias is supposed to be e for employee and m for manager, then the SQL doesn't really make sense

Comment: what sene it makes when using a variable(aliases) of one variable and column of another table(replica)?

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is wrong to start with - right now you're getting the employee ID of the *employee* and the manager ID of the *manager*. So you're skipping a "generation"

I *think* you want:

```
select e.employeeid, m.employeeid
from employee e
left join employee m
on e.managerid=m.employeeid
```

That will give you the employee IDs in the first column and their manager's ID in the second column.

The second one would be the opposite:

```
select e.employeeid, m.employeeid
from employee e
left join employee m
on e.employeeid=m.managerid
```

Would give you the manager ID in the first column and their employee's IDs in the second column.  In that case it would make more sense to swap the `m` and `e` aliases assuming they stand for `manager` and `employee` but that won't change the result.

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/07/08/sql-server-the-self-join-inner-join-and-outer-join/     refer this blog  i want explanation of on condition

Comment: Do you understand how joins work in general?  It;s the same thing here you're just joining a table to itself.

Comment: thats ok,i understand the join in general but here on condition is different thats making me confuse

Answer (score 0):

the first part of your where

`e.managerid=m.employeeid`

will get your subordinate employees

and the second part

`e.employeeid=m.managerid`

will get your manager.

selecting m.managerid in your query doesn't really make sense.. if you look at this sample data and query it might make more sense to you.

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
     employeeid INT,
     managerid INT
    )
INSERT  INTO employee
VALUES  (1,NULL),
        (2,1),
        (3,1),
        (4,2),
        (5,4);

SELECT  e.employeeid employee,
        m.employeeid relatedemployee,
        CASE WHEN e.managerid = m.employeeid THEN 'manager'
             ELSE 'employee'
        END AS relationship
FROM    employee e
        LEFT JOIN employee m ON e.managerid = m.employeeid
                                OR e.employeeid = m.managerid

output:

employee    relatedemployee relationship
----------- --------------- ------------
1           2               employee
1           3               employee
2           1               manager
2           4               employee
3           1               manager
4           2               manager
4           5               employee
5           4               manager
```